# Удаление записи из Stack

Tags: c#, стек, удаление

У меня задание:

При нажатии на кнопку должна удаляться выбранная запись на dataGrid из коллекции. К примеру есть:

```
Stack<Doсument> doсument;
```

Класс документ имеет следующие поля:

```
string name;   //название документа
DateTime data; //дата рассмотрения
string fio;    //ФИО
```

Пробовала реализовать с помощью метода `Pop()`, однако это ж не то... и не знаю как при удалении обновить dataGrid.

Comment: Не используйте `Stack`. Вам больше подойдёт `List`. Или, если используется привязка данных, `BindingList`.

Comment: `Dokument`, `Gried` - ради всего святого, пишите грамотно! Вас же уже поправляли.

Comment: Я не могу использовать List, у меня по заданию Stack

Comment: Вероятно, у вас задание в том и состоит, чтобы научиться работать со стеком. Ну, тогда придётся немножко пострадать. Видимо, от вас требуется создать второй стек и перекладывать объекты в него, пока не будет найден нужный. После его удаления возвращаем в первый стек объекты из второго стека.

Comment: У меня не вяжется `dataGrid` (WPF? Winforms?) и `Stack`. Стек - это LIFO коллекция, последним пришел - первым ушел. Он не предназначен для модификации середины коллекции, при этом просто теряется смысл. Если у вас WPF, то как источник данных используйте `ObservableCollection<T>`, если Winforms, то `BindingList<T>` - это часть, которая отвечает за отображение информации. А в своей бизнес-логике используйте хоть стеки, хоть очереди, что угодно. Кстати, вы ни слова не сказали, какая перед вами стоит задача, а @AlexanderPetrov из-за этого сделал выводы о ее странности. Решение наверняка простое.

Answer (score 0):

Про нецелесообразность использования стека для подобной задачи говорить не буду, ведь "задание есть задание", плюс вам уже написали в комментариях, что в реальном мире для подобных задач стоит использовать списки, к примеру.

Чтобы удалить элемент из стека с нужным индексом, можно путём недолгих размышлений прийти к следующему алгориму:

1. Переместить все элементы перед нужным в дополнительный стек
2. Удалите нужный элемент
3. Переместить все элементы из дополнительного стека обратно

Я, уверен, что у вас получится самостоятельно это реализовать. После этого можете раскрыть спойлер и глянуть мой вариант кода.

Класс с расширением для стека:

> ```
>  public static class StackExtensions
>  {
>      public static T PopAtIndex<T>(this Stack<T> stack, int index)
>      {
>          if (index >= stack.Count)
>              throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
>
>
>          var auxiliaryStack = new Stack();
>
>
>          for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
>              auxiliaryStack.Push(stack.Pop()); // "перекидываем" элементы до нужного во вспомогательный стек
>
>
>          var poppedItem = stack.Pop(); // удаляем нужный элемент
>
>
>          for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
>              stack.Push(auxiliaryStack.Pop()); // "перекидываем" элементы обратно из вспомогательного стека
>
>
>          return poppedItem; // возвращаем удалённый элемент
>      }
>  }
> ```

Пример использования:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var stack = new Stack<float>();
    stack.Push(0f);
    stack.Push(1f);
    stack.Push(2f);
    stack.Push(3f);
    stack.Push(4f);

    Console.WriteLine("Стек до:     " + string.Join(", ", stack));
    Console.WriteLine("Удалён:      " + stack.PopAtIndex(2);
    Console.WriteLine("Стек после:  " + string.Join(", ", stack));
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Стек до:    4, 3, 2, 1, 0
Удалён:     2
Стек после: 4, 3, 1, 0
```